# Firebase no elimina ni enseña proyectos

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase

Estoy empezando con Firebase. Hice un par de proyectos (unos 10...) de prueba y tal y después los eliminaba (o eso pensaba). Ahora ya me he puesto a hacer un proyecto definitivo para una app que tengo y me sale que me quedan dos proyectos para poder crear.

Los otros los he eliminado y no me aparecen en la consola. ¿Los he eliminado del todo?

Otro proyecto que he creado anteriormente pero que he borrado se llama "Sonidos de coches y de motores" y por eso me hace una sugerencia de cambiarle el nombre al proyecto. ¿Pero el proyecto "Sonidos de coches y de motores" está eliminado verdad? ¿Porqué me aparece el aviso del limite de proyectos si en mi consola tengo 0 proyectos?

[image: Pagina principal (no tengo ningún proyecto creado)]

[image: Aviso de limite de proyectos]

Comment: Puede que no los hayas borrado en la [Consola de Google](https://console.cloud.google.com/cloud-resource-manager) o que estés logueado en la cuenta de tu hermano, también desarrollador, y no te hayas dado cuenta (menos probable, pero no imposible) :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando eliminas los proyectos debes aceptar un acuerdo, en uno de los puntos te indica que los dueños del proyecto pueden restaurarlo dentro de 30 días en Google Cloud Console

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**por lo tanto los proyectos que eliminaste en realidad están marcados para eliminación pero aún no están completamente eliminados, debes esperar.**

> **[Recuerda que se requieren 30 días para borrar por completo un
> proyecto](https://firebase.google.com/support/faq), y que este se considera en la cuota hasta que el proceso se
> haya completado.**

---

Por cierto aunque la documentación no indica exactamente el número, usualmente alrededor de 5 a 10 con el plan Spark del nivel gratuito, el número exacto depende de múltiples factores.

Si necesitas más puedes requerir a Google un incremento en el número de proyectos:
https://support.google.com/code/contact/project_quota_increase?authuser=0